# Convert 10-digit string to float

Tags: java, csv

I have a 10-digit string from one of the records in a csv file and I need to convert it to `float` and upload to an Oracle table using prepared statement:

```
String s = '2788539392';

Float f = Float.parseFloat(s);

sql_statement.setFloat(1, f));
```

Why does it changes the value from:

```
csv : 2788539392
java: 2.78853939E9 (float)
oracle: 2788539390
```

Anyone knows how I can preserve the exact values using float?

Comment: float has only ~7 digits of precision and can't store such 10 digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float is limited precision type, there will be rounding errors with numbers this large. This is due to the way a number is represented in the float's bits (for details, see the answer by @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc). If you need to preserve the exact value, use a type like `BigDecimal`.

Comment: float **is** precise, just not like people expected because can't represent most numbers in decimal precisely. And this isn't the problem of this question either because it's about integer values, and double can easily store those numbers

Comment: You're right, `float` is precise within certain boundaries (this specific case is outside of those boundaries). I've updated my answer to "limited precision".

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the number is too big for a float. If you use `BigDecimal` it will preserve the correct value.

```
String s = "2788539392";

BigDecimal d = new BigDecimal(s);
System.out.println(d);
```

I hope this helped. Good luck!

Comment: big for float but not for double

Answer (score 0):

`float` in Java is IEEE-754 single precision which has 24 bits of mantissa, therefore any integers wider than 24 bits will have their precision limited to 24 bits or about 7.2 decimal digits. `double` has 53 bits of mantissa so it can store any integer up to 2<sup>53</sup>-1.

If you need to work with only integers, use `long`, which is a 64-bit type. If you need to store the fractional values in decimal exactly then you must use `BigDecimal`. Otherwise `double` may fit your requirements.